# Resizing partition capacity?

Tags: partitioning, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize Partition with gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

I have a 500GB hard-drive. Now im using Ubuntu 11.04 with Windows 7 (dual boot). My Ubuntu partition capacity is just 20GB. How can I resize it to 50GB (using free space from another partitions)?

Comment: also duplicate of this: 
http://askubuntu.com/q/47409/17789

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [howto](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) on resizing with Windows 7 using Disk Management.

There probably is a way with Ubuntu I just found that easier.