# Problem with installing Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot with Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

Ok, I´m new to Ubuntu, and have been trying it out using WUBI, but now I´ve decided to install it on a dual boot configuration alongside my already existing Windows 7 installation.

So here´s my problem: I have 3 HDD's, Windows 7 being installed on sda, with sdb and sdc only for storage. So I go to the installation process, and click the first option there " Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7". Then I proceed to the next screen where I´m supposed to allocate drive space for the Ubuntu installation. Problem is, it only gives me the option to select my sdc drive, which is one of my storage HDD´s. I can´t choose my sda drive, which is where I have Windows 7 installed.

If I click on the third Install Option, "Something Else", all 3 HDD´s are being detected correctly...

Anyone can help me with this? Would be very grateful! Thanks a lot.

EDIT**

So basically, with just my main 160gb HD plugged in, it let me install on it just fine; If I connect both that and my 320gb HD, it only allow me to choose the 320gb one; If I plug all 3, it only allow me to choose the 500gb one this time. It´s like once there is more than 1 HD connected, It won´t let me install on the one with Windows 7 already installed.

Again, thank you for the help!

Comment: You may want to [shrink a partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47409/shrink-a-partition-without-losing-data) first to make space for Ubuntu. [**Backup first!**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Comment: if I try to shrink a partition first to make space for Ubuntu on my Windows 7 HD, once I select the option to install alongside, it doesn´t let me choose anything at all, it just proceeds to copy the files needed for installation. I didn´t went on to complete the process because I wasn´t sure on which HD it would install it, but after rebooting I did notice that on the Disk Management Ubuntu automatically subdivided my 25gb partition that I created previously for it in two; One was with 20gb, the other was with 4gb. Is that normal?

Comment: Yeah, that's expected. It made a system and a swap partition for you. The installer did not ask you for a choice because there is none except installing Ubuntu to the empty partition (but now this partition is no longer empty of course).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help! I've managed to install it and I'm using in dual boot configuration right now :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7` option is for install **Ubuntu** in the **Windows** partition, so it's fine that you can't see the others HDs. For what do you wanna to do, you have to select the `Something Else` option and install in the partition that you want.

In [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) you will have step by step all the information for install Ubuntu & Windows with dual-boot.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to select the 3rd option where you select all the partitions yourself and then it should automatically set aside some space for you in the unallocated area.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want simple, try simple.

***Can you disable (or unplug) the other 2 HDDs first?***

Comment: As far as unplugging my other 2 HDD's first, yes, then when I go to Ubuntu installation and choose the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" it shows my Windows 7 disk and it let me resize the partition. It´s weird though, as soon as I reconnect any of the other two HD's, Ubuntu automatically 'overrides' my main HD with the Windows 7 installation and only let me choose the other one.

Comment: If you force the location for your primary drive (eg. **/dev/sdc**), then you should be able to get Grub2 working correctly for Windows and Ubuntu.  *You also need further advice from someone who has done this recently.*