# How to merge two partitions separated by another partition?

Tags: 12.10, partitioning

I cant merge these two partitons together like in this picture:

[image]

The NTFS partition is my data, I don't want to delete it. How to merge these two so that I can install Ubuntu?

Comment: Just a wild guess, do you see a raid option there? Or why not put the `/` partition in one, and the `/home` partition in another. Then you don't need to merge them. Both look large enough for the purpose.

Comment: No way to do it. Had sda3 been less full, you could have shrunk it, and moved sda1 and sda2 next to each other, but with 200GB of data, it being 80% full, you'll have to back up, and then delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your partition table I can see three primary partitions.You can only merge adjacent partitions which are same type. The NTFS is fully supported in Ubuntu. You can install Ubuntu in either of sda1 or sda2 because, both of them have exuberant space for a Ubuntu system. After installing Ubuntu you can use the NTFS partition as you did it in windows.

If you want to merge sda1 & sda3 so badly, then you have to delete one of the ext2 partition and use that unallocated space to move NTFS partition by making unallocated space available adjacent to your Ubuntu installation partition. Then you can use the unallocated space to resize your Ubuntu installation partition. Warning! Backup your data because this is quiet dangerous.

I hope the following threads would be helpful.

[Can Ubuntu move partition boundaries without losing data within them?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1673001)

[Shrink a partition without losing data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47409/shrink-a-partition-without-losing-data)