# Partition for other Linux Distros

Tags: partitioning

I have 320 GB of HDD and installed Ubuntu to all partition but what if I want to install debian or any other linux distro to the remaning drive parts that are not in use ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say that you installed ubuntu to _all_. Stands to reason that then there are no remaining parts big enough to install another distro. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most easy way is to use gparted on a live usb or DVD. to resize a partition you need to unmount and since you cannot unmount your root partition you cannot do it from your normal Ubuntu install. in the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47409/shrink-a-partition-without-losing-data) question is a quick overview how to use gparted.