# Editing system partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, resize

There is only one partition in my hard disk. I want to give a partiton on it. Is  there any way to resize it without using any live cd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on the underlying filesystem BUT in most cases its NOT recommended to do this anyway - except you are using a LVM which is designed to do this.

With only one partition its sure that this one is the root partition and that is used (mounted) when your system runs...

WHY don't you want to use a live cd?

Comment: Will live cd erase my all data?

Comment: no, of course not. a live cd just boots a operating system from a cd. the besser question is: "Will all my date be lost then i shrink a partition?" - The answer is: DEPENDS on the software you use to do this... see  this: http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted "Modify Your Partitions With GParted Without Losing Data" or see askubuntu.com: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47409/shrink-a-partition-without-losing-data

Comment: ok i'm trying :)