# How do I split my unified root & home folder after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: root, ssd, home-directory, split

I need some help over here. I want to split my Ubuntu partition (which contains the root and the home folder) to two separate partitions, so I could only move my root partition to my SSD afterwards. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it may be easier to do a fresh install as you are going to have to copy large amounts of data and likely manually modify fstab and grub. If you want to do this, you will need to do it from a live CD, make new partitions, copy the data to the new partitions, and then edit fstab and re-install grub.

Comment: Do you have any freespace/partition in this computer?

Comment: I have only 108GB left on my HDD while 166GB is already used (the partition has a size of 276GB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible without a fresh installation but takes a bit of time and effort. Below are the steps:

**1. Create a New Partition**

If you have enough free space, you can directly use that as a partition by formatting it into an ext4 using gparted. If you do not have free space you should resize your partition (see [Shrink a partition without losing data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47409/shrink-a-partition-without-losing-data) )

**2. Copy `/home` to newly created partition**

Mount the new partition if it is not already mounted. Copy `/home` to new partition by:

> `sudo cp -Rp /home/* /mount/location/of/new-partition`

**3. Modify the `fstab` File**

First ge the uuid of the new partition by running:

> `sudo blkid`

and backup the existing `fstab` file by:

> `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab_backup`

Now, open `/etc/fstab` by:

> `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

Add the following on a newline. Add the uuid of your newly created partition

> `UUID=<your-uuid-here>     /home     ext4     nodev,nosuid     0     2`

Save and exit.

**4. Move your `home`**

> `cd / && sudo mv /home /home_old && sudo mkdir /home`

Restart your computer and remove home_old by:

`sudo rm -rf /home_old`

Reference: http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/

Comment: That is part 1, making a new home. Now you need part 2, moving the root partition to another drive, updating fsatab again, and updating grub.

Comment: oops I missed it! Moving root requires to boot from live CD/USB. The following post detail the procedures: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40372/how-to-move-ubuntu-to-an-ssd