# Split (root+home) into / and /home, with limited space

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, home-directory

I have a system with a single (`/`+`/home`) partition, with 275Gb and 18Gb free.
As per `du`, my `/home` takes 221Gb, so `/` would be about 36Gb.
I want to split it into `/` and `/home` partitions.

Besides the fact that would first free some, say, 40Gb, to lessen the burden, **is there any way to partition other than copying all `/home` somewhere else where I have those ~200Gb available?**

The "classical" recipe (e.g., [1](https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630311/how-do-i-split-my-unified-root-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu), [3](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)) uses that, and implies ending with `/` with 275Gb and `/home` with ~200Gb.
Of course, I could then remove `home_old`, reduce the size of `/`, create a new partition in the freed space, and copy `/home` back in the new partition (which would also free the auxiliary ~200Gb).
That is my current plan, but I have to get those extra 200Gb, currently not available. I mean to avoid that, if possible at all.

Comment: Yes, probably, BUT it requires a familiarity with with disks, partitions, filesystems, their structures, tools for working with all of the above, a Live USB, and a willingness to risk losing all your data. How's your power reliability? Air conditioning? Attention span?

Comment: @waltinator - Assuming I have the resources, what is the suggested method?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is not a conversation site. If you're well educated enough, the method suggests itself. If not, it's like disarming a bomb with the expert on the telephone.

Comment: @waltinator - Of course I am willing to edit my question with whatever information people willing to help ask about.
I apologize I missed what is it you mean that I add, would you mind clarifying?
I guessed you didn't mean that I add details in the OP about my air conditioning, attention span, etc. But I might have gotten it wrong.

Comment: It's too dangerous (for you), and I won't risk my honor on it. You will lose data. Use the referenced methods.

Comment: @waltinator - Ok fair enough. I wouldn't see how describing a method, however dangerous (with due warnings), might risk your well-earned honor (your answers and comments are always a reference). There are plenty of such posts around (SE and others), by quite reputable people. You won't, by any means, be possibly held responsible for whatever data loss I suffer. But of course, I respect your choice.
PS: I already reduced my `/home` to the point that I have technically enough room to resize and make the transfer in my own drive.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/226614) should work.