# Need advise on ubuntu partition to install opensuse in dual boot

Tags: partitioning

I have ubuntu 12.04 with below details shown by gparted. Is there any possibility i can squeeze around 100GB from "/" for open suse, or anyway can i install opensuse without damaging current installation.

```
/dev/sda1/   fat32         DELLUTILITY  
/dev/sda2/   fat32         OS  
/dev/sda3/   ext4    /     boot  454 GB   128 GB used  
/dev/sda4/   extended  
    /dev/sda5    linux swap    7 GB
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shrink a partition without losing data](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47409/shrink-a-partition-without-losing-data)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 128GB out of 450GB used on `sda3`, you can definitely downsize the partition to install OpenSUSE. Open Gparted in Ubuntu and use it to make `sda3` a little smaller. Then select `Apply`. **Make sure not to format it or resize the wrong partition**.